# How to pass C.ulong inter process?

Tags: c, linux, go, cgo

In order to reuse CGO pointers (type C.uintptr_t) between multiple applications, I tried to use go rpc to pass the initialized pointer, but the program reported an error: rpc: gob error encoding body: gob: type not registered for interface: main._Ctype_ulong. I think there might be some issues with pointer types.

**1. init func**

```
func initApp(configPath *C.char) C.uintptr_t
```

**2. App1, daemon process, call the init func, and pass the pointer to another by go rpc**

```
var globalSDKPtr C.ulong

type HelloService struct{}

func (p *HelloService) Hello(request string, reply *C.ulong) error {
    *reply = globalSDKPtr
    return nil
}

func startRPS() {
    rpc.RegisterName("HelloService", new(HelloService))

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenTCP error:", err)
    }

    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Accept error:", err)
    }

    rpc.ServeConn(conn)
}
```

**3. App2, recevie the pointer reuse it.**

```
client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", "localhost:1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dialing:", err)
    }

    var reply C.ulong
    err = client.Call("HelloService.Hello", "hello", &reply)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    res := C.query(reply)
```

I guess the reason for the problem is that my thinking is wrong. The way to reuse cgo pointers may not be the way of go rpc, but shared memory, but in any case, passing cgo-related things is always confusing. . Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Passing a pointer to another process is meaningless. Even if it points to shared memory, the base address of a shared memory region differs in each process. You should be passing around offsets from the start of shared memory instead of raw pointers.

Comment: thank you, i wil take a try, and later update the question.@rustyx